# How to put 2 formulas instead of range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a complex sheet working with the Filter formula, and I want to do the following:

```
=arrayformula(Roster!A3:A)
```

```
=FILTER(Roster!G3:BZ,Roster!G2:BZ2=U6)
```

now I want to do vlookup for using the above 2 formulas as following:

```
=VLOOKUP($T$7:$T$110,**$X$7**:**$Y$830**,2,0)
```

The range $X7 = `=arrayformula(Roster!A3:A)`

The range $Y$830 = `=FILTER(Roster!G3:BZ,Roster!G2:BZ2=U6)`

How i can compound the 2 formulas?

Comment: thats the formula in the end =VLOOKUP($T$7:$T$110,$X$7:$Y$830,2,0)


i want to it to be like that but its actually not working:


=VLOOKUP(arrayformula(Roster!A3:A):FILTER(Roster!G3:BZ,Roster!G2:BZ2=U6),$X$7:$Y$830,2,0)

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(T7:T110, 
 FILTER({Roster!A3:A, Roster!G3:BZ}, Roster!G2:BZ2=U6), 2, 0)))
```